# Android password visibility toogle not showing

Tags: android, layout

The icon doesn't want to show up. I notice that when I add `app:passwordToogleEnabled ='true'`the height of the textinputlayer moves. However the icon doesnt show up.

```xml
 <!--  Password Label -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/visibility_off-24px"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/mainBlue"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:background="@drawable/edt_txt_bg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sf_compact_display_medium"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:text="sOlUcOm2020" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

EDIT : My icon was in svg format istead of xml, that's why it didn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this code

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

and XML

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Passowrd"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/Password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

EDIT : Your icon will be in svg format instead of xml, that's why it didn't show up.